# Javascript - Update a deep object in another object using a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
obj1
   id
   name
   obj2[]
     id
     name
     description
```

I want to update obj2 where the id = x. What I have right now is `obj1.obj2.find(x => x.id == 1)`.
When I update it's values I have to call it over and over.

Ex.
`obj1.obj2.find(x => x.id == 1).name = 'John'; obj1.obj2.find(x => x.id == 1).description = 'small'`

How can I do without using find over and over?

Comment: Assign `obj1.obj2.find(x => x.id == 1)` to a name?

Comment: Is `obj2` an array of objects? Since objects don't have a `find` method but arrays do.

Comment: Show the actual code, hard to know what that block of indented text is supposed to represent.

Comment: Yep my bad. Obj2 is an array of objects. This is just a bathroom thought that's why I don't have the code on hand. Will update again once I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others, I assume `obj2` holds an array of object. Instead, you could use an object, each key being the id you are looking for.

```
obj2: [
    {
    id: 1b12c,
    name: 'foo',
    description: 'bar',
    },
    {
      id: 2pop2,
      name: 'foo2',
      description: 'bar2',
    },
]
```

would be

```
obj2: {
    1b12c : {
        name: 'foo',
        description: 'bar',
    },
    2pop2: {
      name: 'foo2',
      description: 'bar2',
    }
}
```

Thanks to that, your code would be like `obj1.obj2[id]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `obj2` holds an array of objects, since there is no `.find()` method on objects but on arrays, you can simply store the reference to the object and then use `Object.assign()`, which modifies the object in place:

```js
const obj1 = {
  id: 99,
  name: 'bar',
  obj2: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'lorem',
    description: 'foobar',
  }]
};

// Before change
console.log(obj1.obj2);

const target = obj1.obj2.find(x => x.id === 1);
Object.assign(target, {
  name: 'John',
  description: 'small',
});

// After change
console.log(obj1.obj2);
```